# uninstall visual studio 2017 installer from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2017, build-automation

I am using windows 10.
I want to uninstall "visual studio installer" from command line. Is it even possible ? I researched around but could not find a way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

This works, but also uninstalls Visual Studio:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" /uninstall --passive
```

Found in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6F320B93-EE3C-4826-85E0-ADF79F8D4C61}
```